# Written lines not in correct order | io.open & write

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I did this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(fullpath, encoding='utf8'), "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll('a', style='text-decoration: none !important;')
    for link in links:
        txtfile.write(link['data-title'] + '\n')
```

I need to use `io.open` because otherwise I get an error, but with `io.open` the extracted lines are not in the correct order as it has been read.

How to make `io.open` read & write in the order as the lines has been read?

Comment: Can you please provide either a link to the file or a replicateable example of the input?